# Powershell command to sync Office 365 user to Mailchimp

Tags: powershell, office365, mailchimp

I found a Powershell script that sync's Office 365 users to Mailchimp contacts. It works well, but the only issue is that I want it to either "Unsubscribe" or "Archive" contacts in Mailchimp IF a previously licensed user in Office 365 no longer has any active licenses.

Right now it will update licenses if a users license is changed in Office 365, but not if all licenses have been removed. I think the following line in the script is what's causing users with no licenses to not sync, but I don't know the best way to remedy it...

`$users = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.islicensed}`

If I change this line to `$users = Get-MsolUser -All` then it will retrieve users regardless of if they are licensed or not, but this still doesn't quite resolve my problem since my goal is to still only sync licensed users, but to ensure that once an O365 user is unlicensed, that they will be "Unsubscribed" or "Archived" in Mailchimp (either is fine).

I am pasting the entire script below and added a <------ next to the line of code I mentioned above (which is about 3/4 of the way down). Any ideas on how I can adjust the script to accomplish my goal would be greatly appreciated.

```
$user = "abc"
$apiKey = "544492bf22f6895d4ae-us15"
$pair = "${user}:${apiKey}"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"
$Headers = @{
   Authorization = $basicAuthValue 
}
$baseUri = "https://us15.api.mailchimp.com"
$listInfo = @{
   listName            = "Office 365 Customer Sync"
   company             = "abc"
   address1            = "abc"
   address2            = " "
   city                = "abc"
   state               = "NY"
   zip                 = "11111"
   country             = "US"
   phone               = ""
   permission_reminder = "You are receiving this email because you are a client of Abtech Technologies"
   from_name           = "John Doe"
   from_email          = "jdoe@email.com"
   subject             = ""
   language            = "en"
}
$Office365members = @()
Connect-MsolService

function Ensure-MailChimpList ($ListName) {
   $lists = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists?offset=0"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
   if ($lists.lists.name -notcontains $ListName) {
       $list = New-MailChimpList -ListInfo $listInfo
       return $list
   }
   else {
       $list = $lists.lists | Where-object {$_.name -contains $listName}
       return $list
   }
}


function New-MailChimpList ($ListInfo) {
   $listBody = @{
       name                = $listInfo.listName
       contact             = @{
           company  = $listInfo.company
           address1 = $listInfo.address1
           address2 = $listInfo.address2
           city     = $listInfo.city
           state    = $listInfo.state
           zip      = $listInfo.zip
           country  = $listInfo.country
           phone    = $listInfo.phone
       }
       permission_reminder = $listInfo.permission_reminder
       campaign_defaults   = @{
           from_name  = $listInfo.from_name
           from_email = $listInfo.from_email
           subject    = $listInfo.subject
           language   = $listInfo.language
       }
       email_type_option   = $false
   }

   $listBody = $listBody | ConvertTo-Json

   $newList = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $listBody
   return $newList
}

function Get-MailChimpListSegments {
   $segments = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/segments?offset=0"&"count=200 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
   return $segments
}

function Get-MailChimpListMergeFields {
   $mergeFields = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/merge-fields -Method Get -Headers $Headers
   return $mergeFields
}

function New-MailChimpListMergeField ($Name, $Type, $Tag) {
   $merge_field = @{
       name = $Name
       type = $Type
       tag  = $Tag
   }
   $merge_field = $merge_field | ConvertTo-Json
   Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/merge-fields -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $merge_field
}

function New-MailChimpListBatch ($MemberBatch) {

   $body = @{
       members         = $MemberBatch
       update_existing = $true
   }
   
   $body = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

   $batchresult = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $body
   return $batchresult
}
function New-MailChimpListMember ($email, $FirstName, $LastName, $Company, $Licenses) {
   
   $merge_fields = @{
       FNAME    = $FirstName
       LNAME    = $LastName
       COMPANY  = $Company
       LICENSES = $Licenses
   }

   
   $member = @{
       email_address = $email
       status        = "subscribed"
       merge_fields  = $merge_fields
   }
   return $member
}
function Update-MailChimpListMember ($ExistingMember, $Office365Member) {
   
   $merge_fields = @{
       FNAME    = $Office365Member.FirstName
       LNAME    = $Office365Member.LastName
       COMPANY  = $Office365Member.Company
       LICENSES = $Office365Member.Licenses
   }

   
   $member = @{
       email_address = $Office365Member.Email
       status        = $existingMember.Status
       merge_fields  = $merge_fields
   }
   return $member
}

# function Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember ($ExistingMember) {

  # $member = @{
   #   email_address = $ExistingMember.Email
  #     status        = "unsubscribed"
  # }
  # return $member

#   Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members/$($existingMember.SubscriberHash) -Method PATCH -Headers $Headers -Body $member
# }

function Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers {
   $existingMembers = $null
   $existingmembers = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members?offset=0"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
   for ($i = 100; $i -le $existingMembers.total_items; $i += 100) {
       $members = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/members?offset=$i"&"count=100 -Method Get -Headers $Headers
       $existingMembers.members += $members.members
   }
   return $existingMembers
}

function New-LicenseSegment ($SkuPartNumber) {
   $conditions = @()
   
   $conditionproperty = @{
       condition_type = "TextMerge"
       field          = "LICENSES"
       op             = "contains"
       value          = $SkuPartNumber.TrimStart("License: ")
   }
   $conditions += $conditionproperty
   
   $segment = @{
       name    = $SkuPartNumber
       options = @{
           match      = "any"
           conditions = $conditions
       }
   }
   
   $segment = $segment | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
   
   $newSegment = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $baseUri/3.0/lists/$listId/segments -Method POST -Headers $Headers -Body $segment
   return $newSegment
}

function Create-ExistingMemberCollection ($ExistingMembers) {
   
   $existingMemberCollection = @()
   foreach ($existingmember in $existingmembers) {
       
       $memberObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
           Licenses       = $existingmember.merge_fields.LICENSES
           FirstName      = $existingmember.merge_fields.FNAME
           LastName       = $existingmember.merge_fields.LNAME
           Company        = $existingmember.merge_fields.COMPANY
           Email          = $existingmember.email_address
           SubscriberHash = $existingmember.id
           Status         = $existingmember.status
       }
       $existingMemberCollection += $memberObject
   }
   

   return $existingMemberCollection
}

function Create-UploadBatch ($collection) {
   # Upload the collection in batches of 100
   $counter = [pscustomobject] @{ Value = 0 }
   $batchsize = 100
   $batches = $collection | Group-Object -Property { [math]::Floor($counter.Value++ / $batchSize) }
   foreach ($batch in $batches) { New-MailChimpListBatch -MemberBatch $batch.Group}
}


# Check whether list exists and create it if it doesn't
$listID = (Ensure-MailChimpList -ListName $listInfo.listName).id

# Check for current merge fields in list
Write-Host "Retrieving Merge Fields"
$mergeFields = Get-MailChimpListMergeFields
$updateSegments = $false

$requiredMergeFields = "Company", "Licenses"
foreach ($requiredMergeField in $requiredMergeFields) {
   if (!$mergeFields.merge_fields.Name.contains($requiredMergeField)) {
       Write-Host "Creating Merge Field: $requiredMergeField" -ForegroundColor Yellow
       $newMergeField = New-MailChimpListMergeField -Name $requiredMergeField -Type text -Tag $requiredMergeField.ToUpper()
   }
}


# Retrieve existing segments, then filter by license related segments
$existingSegments = Get-MailChimpListSegments
$existingLicenseSegments = $existingSegments | Where-Object {$_.segments.name -match "License: "}
$requiredSegments = @()


# Create collection containing required info for all users in all tenants

Write-Host "Retrieving users and license info" -ForegroundColor Blue
$users = $null
$users = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {$_.islicensed}   <----------------------------------------------
$company = (Get-MsolCompanyInformation).DisplayName
foreach ($user in $users) {
   [string[]]$userLicenses = $null
   foreach ($license in $user.Licenses.AccountSku.SkuPartNumber) {
       $userLicenses += "'$license'"
   }
   $userLicensesString = $userLicenses -join ','
       

   # Check if these licenses already have segments created or queued
   foreach ($license in $userlicenses) {
       $expectedSegmentName = "License: $license"
       if ($existingLicenseSegments.segments.Name -notcontains $expectedSegmentName -and $requiredSegments -notcontains $expectedSegmentName) {
           $requiredSegments += $expectedSegmentName
           Write-Host "Adding $expectedSegmentName to required segments list. Update pending." -ForegroundColor Yellow
           $updateSegments = $true
       }
   }

   $firstName = $user.FirstName
   if (!$user.FirstName) {
       $firstName = $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]
   }
   $lastName = $user.LastName
   if (!$user.lastName -and !$user.firstname) {
       $lastName = $user.DisplayName.Split(" ") | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]}
       $lastName = $lastName -join " "
   }
   elseif (!$user.lastName -and $user.firstname) {
       $lastname = ""
   }
   elseif (!$user.LastName -and !($user.DisplayName.Split(" ") | Where-Object {$_ -notcontains $user.DisplayName.Split(" ")[0]})) {
       $lastname = ""
   }
       
   $email = $user.UserPrincipalName
   $memberObject = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
       Licenses  = $userLicensesString
       FirstName = $firstName
       LastName  = $lastName
       Company   = $company
       Email     = $email
   }
   $Office365members += $memberObject
}

Write-Host "Retrieved $($office365Members.count) licensed users" -ForegroundColor Green

# If an update is required, add new segments
if ($updateSegments) {
   Write-Host "New segments required: $requiredSegments" -ForegroundColor Green
   # Create new license segments

   if ($requiredSegments.count -gt 0) {
       foreach ($requiredSegment in $requiredSegments) {
           Write-Host "Creating new segment - $requiredSegment" -ForegroundColor Blue
           $newSegment = New-LicenseSegment -SkuPartNumber $requiredSegment
       }
   }
}

# Check if members exist in list
# Build list of existing members

Write-Host "Getting existing members"

$existingMembers = (Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers).members

$newMemberCollection = @()

# Check if Office 365 users already exist in mailchimp. If they don't, add them to a collection for upload
foreach ($member in $Office365members) {
   if ($existingMembers.email_address -notcontains $member.Email) {
       Write-Host "Adding $($member.firstName) $($member.lastName) to new subscriber collection" -ForegroundColor Green
       $newMemberObject = New-MailChimpListMember -email $member.Email -FirstName $member.FirstName -LastName $member.LastName -Licenses $member.Licenses -Company $member.Company
       $newMemberCollection += $newMemberObject
   }
}

Create-UploadBatch -collection $newMemberCollection

# Retrieve updated list of existing members

$existingMembers = (Get-ExistingMailChimpListMembers).members
$existingMemberCollection = Create-ExistingMemberCollection -ExistingMembers $existingMembers

# Update users when details have changed.

$updatedMemberCollection = @()
foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
   $office365Member = $null
   $office365Member = $Office365members | Where-Object {$_.Email -contains $existingMember.Email}
   if ($office365member) {
       if ($office365Member.FirstName -notmatch $existingMember.FirstName -or `
               $office365Member.LastName -notmatch $existingMember.LastName -or `
               $office365Member.Licenses -notmatch $existingMember.Licenses -or `
               $office365Member.Company -notmatch $existingMember.Company){
           
           Write-Host "Updating record for $($existingMember.Email)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
           $updatedMemberObject = Update-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember -Office365Member $office365Member
           $updatedMemberCollection += $updatedMemberObject
           
       }
   }
}

Create-UploadBatch ($updatedMemberCollection)

# Unsubscribe users who no longer exist in Office 365

# $unsubscribedMemberCollection = @()
# foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
#    if ($Office365members.License -notcontains $existingmember.License -and $existingmember.status -notcontains "unsubscribed") {
#        Write-Host "$($existingmember.License) is no longer licensed in Office 365, unsubscribing." -ForegroundColor Red
#        $unsubscribedMemberObject = Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember
#        $unsubscribedMemberCollection += $unsubscribedMemberObject 
#    }
# }

# Create-UploadBatch ($unsubscribedMemberCollection)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last few lines you have supplied, it looks like the code's author already attempted to solve this problem, but perhaps was either unable to get it working or it was no longer required, and so they commented it out. Here's your existing code with no modifications:

```
# Unsubscribe users who no longer exist in Office 365

$unsubscribedMemberCollection = @()
foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
   if ($Office365members.License -notcontains $existingmember.License -and $existingmember.status -notcontains "unsubscribed") {
       Write-Host "$($existingmember.License) is no longer licensed in Office 365, unsubscribing." -ForegroundColor Red
       $unsubscribedMemberObject = Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember
       $unsubscribedMemberCollection += $unsubscribedMemberObject 
   }
}

Create-UploadBatch ($unsubscribedMemberCollection)
```

On a cursory examination, one key change stands out - `$existingmember.License` is no longer singular in your running code, it's now a collection of `$existingmember.Licenses`, and so this *could* be one reason that the previously designed unsubscribe approach doesn't work as expected. **I'm proceeding with this answer on the assumption that the *unsubscribe* behaviour works fine**, but that you're just missing the means to correctly identify users with no current licenses.

Currently this code retrieves the list of licenses with `$Office365members.License`, and then checks whether it contains the license stored for the `$existingmember`. If an `$existingmember` were to have one license removed but another license was still correct, the above code would unsubscribe them. So we need to refactor the code to only take action on users who do not currently have any licenses:

```
# Unsubscribe users who no longer exist in Office 365
    
$unsubscribedMemberCollection = @()
foreach ($existingMember in $existingMemberCollection) {
    # create a new object to hold a list of True/False values for each checked license        
    $licenseCheck = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new() 
    forEach($license in $existingMember.Licenses){
        if ($Office365members.License -notcontains $License -and $existingmember.status -notcontains "unsubscribed") {
            # Add $false for a non-existent license
            [void]$licenseCheck.Add($false) 
            Write-Host "$($License) not found." -ForegroundColor Red
        }else{
            # Add $true wherever the user still has a valid license
            [void]$licenseCheck.Add($true)  
            #Write-Host "$($existingmember.License) found." -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }

    # Trigger the unsubscribe if the user does not have any valid licenses
    if($licenseCheck -notcontains $true){   
        Write-Host "$($License) is no longer licensed in Office 365, unsubscribing." -ForegroundColor Red
        $unsubscribedMemberObject = Unsubscribe-MailChimpListMember -ExistingMember $existingMember
        $unsubscribedMemberCollection += $unsubscribedMemberObject 
    }
}
    
Create-UploadBatch ($unsubscribedMemberCollection)
```

I'll add that the above code is imperfect in that it will unsubscribe a user with *no valid licenses* (which I think is the required behaviour), but will not update their licenses if they still hold at least one valid license. But then again, you said that your other functions already do that, so I'm operating under the assumption that this code only needs to cover cases where existing users have had all their licenses removed.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will test out the script and get back with you. Happy New Year and thanks for putting this together for me.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyFilmore, hope it does the job!

Comment: @JeffreyFilmore - if this was helpful, do feel free to upvote and/or Accept the answer